# Swift. Can't change structure's property, received form array

Tags: ios, swift, struct, swift-protocols

I have a problem with updating my array of generic structures which are `[SelectableItem]` in the example below.

[Quick 40 seconds video screencast with a problem.](https://www.screencast.com/t/uxw3aS2En3n)

So I have an `UITableView` with datasource of `[SelectableItem]`. At first time when I init this array where I specify name and selected states, table view shows data correctly. But when I try to select `SelectableItem` and switch `isSelected` Bool state to true and reload data then, the source `SelectableItem` `isSelected` property is still `false` when cell try to get it via the same `getModelAt` func.

```
protocol Selectable {
    var isSelected: Bool { get set }
}

struct SelectableItem: Selectable {

    var isSelected: Bool
    let name: String
}

func getModelAt(_ indexPath: IndexPath) -> T {
        return isSearchActive ? searchResults[indexPath.item] : models[indexPath.item]
    }

@objc(tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:) func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){
        if var model = strongDataSource?.getModelAt(indexPath) {
            model.isSelected = !model.isSelected
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

on this line `model.isSelected = !model.isSelected` all goes well and I see name of model and how `model.isSelected` switched to another value (from false to true for example and form true to false).

My assumption that as I use structures instead of classes, maybe my `getModelAt` returns to me a model by value from array not by reference. But I am not 100% sure. Or maybe something wrong with `Protocol get set`

Not sure if it will be helpful to understand my question, but I used this [link](https://medium.com/@jamesrochabrun/advance-generics-to-create-reusable-ui-f0b8b8934895) to implement search functionality and I just extended it with selection functionality. So all works good excluding assignment new values for `isSelected` property of structure instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a `struct` assignment means copying and changing it does't affect the main reference

```
if var model = strongDataSource?.getModelAt(indexPath) {
```

so you need to make `SelectableItem` a class